# Search query using MongoMapper/Ruby with variable parameters not working

Tags: ruby, variables, mongodb, mongomapper

I want to return all cards under a certain category. I have the following query that works using MongoMapper and is returning results correctly:

```
@cards = Card.where(:category_ids => 2)
```

However I want to be able to query the category based on a variable like this:

```
@cards = Card.where(:category_ids => params[:cat_id])
```

Where cat_id is being passed as HTTP get. But for some reason this returns no results. Does MongoMapper support passing in variables to search in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a type problem. The values in `params` will be strings but you want a Fixnum. Try this:

```
@cards = Card.where(:category_ids => params[:cat_id].to_i)
```

MongoMapper's `where` won't do all the type conversions for you.